# apt packages without manual pages

Tags: apt, man

When I look at what I have installed via `apt list --installed`, why are there so many entries without manual pages?

I tried `info [package name]` and `package name --help`
and get the output

```
bash: package name: command not found
```

Comment: Not all packages are command line utilities.

Comment: Ok great so, what are they and or where can I find documentation regarding their purpose?\

Comment: `dpkg -L package | grep /man | xargs -L 1 basename`

Comment: Online list of binary packages with man pages in [Debian stretch](https://manpages.debian.org/contents-stretch.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People think that you are looking for manual pages, because *you* erroneously think that you are looking for manual pages.  To see descriptions of what the packages in that list actually are, use:

- `aptitude show ${PACKAGE_NAME}`
- `apt show ${PACKAGE_NAME}`

## Further reading

- [https://packages.debian.org./*package-name*](https://packages.debian.org./)

Answer (score 0):

[man](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) [binary name] is the useful syntax to enter at the command line.

Comment: It's not the `package name` but the binary that comes with it provided that it has a man page. The man pages are found in `/usr/share/man/man#` where `man#` corresponds to `/usr/share/man/man1`, `/usr/share/man/man2` and so on and so forth.